# What is the openssl -new option for?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

If I create a selfsigned certificate I can omit or include the -new option with no obvious difference.
Assume I have a private key in the file privkey.pem.

```
openssl req -x509 -key privkey.pem -out selfcertnonew.pem

openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out selfcertwithnew.pem
```

What is the difference between the certificates in the files selfcertnonew.pem and selfcertwithnew.pem

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the openssl source code, the '-x509' option *implies* the '-new' option.

Reference:

- https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/req.c ... line 293.